# Change of styling based on TypeScript function return

Tags: javascript, css, svelte

I am trying to change the visibility style of a div element in a svelte component based on a typescript function.

The sample code is like the ones below:

```
<script>
const abc = () => {
    if (RecipientNumberOffScreen == 0) {
      return document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.recipients__OffScreen').style.visibility =  'hidden'
    } else {
      return RecipientNumberOffScreen // a calculated variable
    }
}
</script>

<div class="recipients">
  <div class="recipients__OffScreen">{abc()}</div>
</div>
```

And I am getting the following error in the console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

What I could understand by debugging that the `document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.recipients__OffScreen')` is getting `null` value because first the JS gets loaded in the DOM, and then the html codes are being loaded. I was wondering if there is any way to make the function execution wait before the html gets loaded in svelte? Or what is the best way to achieving it?

I am very new to svelte, thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not query the DOM in Svelte. Please do the [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial) if you have not done so...

Comment: This article might be of interest https://geoffrich.net/posts/clean-component-tips/#heading-work-with-the-component-template-not-against-it